# Optimize mysql DB execution using JDBC in Android

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc, android-asynctask

I have some code in android which is running a query to the database which i have hosted online.
I have used AsyncTask to perform DB operation in this activity, similarly I have other activities too which are having similar code and connection procedure. I wanted to know if this is the optimal way to connect to mysql db using JDBC connection in android or can this be improved

The code is taking around 3 sec for login as in MainActivity class.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ProgressDialog mProgress;
final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE = 1000;

private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.103/pos";
private static final String user = "root";
private static final String pass = "";
private EditText mPassword, mUsername;
private Button loginBtn;
private ProgressBar mLoginProgress;
private TextView mLoginFeedbackText;
String password, username;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
Boolean CheckEditText;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    if (!checkPermissionFromDevice())
        requestPermission();

    mPassword = findViewById(R.id.password);
    mUsername = findViewById(R.id.username);
    loginBtn = findViewById(R.id.generate_btn);
    mLoginProgress = findViewById(R.id.login_progress_bar);
    mLoginFeedbackText = findViewById(R.id.login_form_feedback);
    mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    
    loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            CheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot();
            if (CheckEditText) {
                UserLoginFunction(username, password);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please fill all form fields.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void CheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot() {
    username = mUsername.getText().toString();
    password = mPassword.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username) || TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        CheckEditText = false;
    } else {
        CheckEditText = true;
    }
}

private void requestPermission() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
    }, REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE);
}

private boolean checkPermissionFromDevice() {
    int write_external_storage_result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int record_audio_result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
    return write_external_storage_result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            record_audio_result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}
public void UserLoginFunction(final String username, final String password) {
    class UserLoginClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            System.out.println("In onPreExecute");
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Loading Data", null, true, true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String httpResponseMsg) {
            System.out.println("In onPostExecute");
            super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg);

            progressDialog.dismiss();

            if (httpResponseMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("It matches")) {

                finish();

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartActivity.class);
                System.out.println("USERNAME" + username);
                intent.putExtra("USERNAME", username);
                startActivity(intent);

            } else {
                mLoginFeedbackText.setText("Verification Failed, please try again.");
                mLoginFeedbackText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mLoginProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                loginBtn.setEnabled(true);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, httpResponseMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            System.out.println("In doInBackground");
            try {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);

                Statement st = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='BobMartin'");


                while (rs.next()) {
                    String queryPassword = rs.getString("password");
                    String hash_php = queryPassword.replaceFirst("2y", "2a");
                    if (BCrypt.checkpw(password, hash_php)) {
                        con.close();
                        System.out.println("It matches");
                        return "It matches";
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("It does not match");
                        return "It does not match";
                    }
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("result in catch");
            }
            return "It does not match";
        }
    }
    UserLoginClass userLoginClass = new UserLoginClass();
    userLoginClass.execute(username, password);
}


}
```

Similarly for other activity also im again creating connection and closing them in the similar manner as shown.

```
public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button startButton;
String userName;
private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.103/pos";
private static final String user = "root";
private static final String pass = "";

ArrayList<String> dbQuestions = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> dbAnswers = new ArrayList<String>();

ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    userName = getIntent().getStringExtra("USERNAME");
    new StartDb().execute();

    startButton = findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("USERNAMEstart" + userName);
            Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, BillActivity.class);
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putSerializable("ANSWERS", (Serializable) dbAnswers);
            args.putSerializable("QUESTIONS", (Serializable) dbQuestions);
            intent.putExtra("USERNAME", userName);
            intent.putExtra("BUNDLE", args);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // super.onBackPressed();
    Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this, "There is no back action", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return;
}

class StartDb extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        System.out.println("In onPreExecute");
        super.onPreExecute();

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(StartActivity.this, "Loading Data", null, true, true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String httpResponseMsg) {
        System.out.println("In onPostExecute");
        super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        System.out.println("In doInBackground");
        try {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);

            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `company_details`");

            while (rs.next()) {

                String que = rs.getString("questions");
                JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject(que);
                for (Iterator<String> it = obj1.keys(); it.hasNext(); ) {
                    String key = it.next();
                    dbQuestions.add(obj1.getString(key));
                }

                String ans = rs.getString("answers");
                JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject(ans);
                for (Iterator<String> it = obj2.keys(); it.hasNext(); ) {
                    String key = it.next();
                    dbAnswers.add(obj2.getString(key));
                }

                con.close();
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("resilt in catch");
        }
        return "It does not match";
    }
}

}
```

Please suggest how can i increase execution time.

Comment: You really use mysql directly from your App?  Don‘t do it.

Comment: I assume you mean "decrease" execution time. @jens is absolutely right. Don't hit your MySql data base directly from your mobile app.  Instead, set up a web service to hit the database, and hit the web service from your mobile app.  The web service can connect to, and use, the database much more efficiently than your app code can. And it's much more secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL protocol does not perform at all well over long distances. Its just a fact.

If you need to access MySQL over a long distance, you should put a rest/api in front of the database, running as physically close to the MySQL as you can, then get your app to query that, e.g. running multiple API-Gateways in containers for fail-over & load-balancing.

`[MySQL]-[REST/API Gateway]-----------{Internet}------------[Client]`

I've never used it, but looks like this sort of thing will do what you want - https://www.progress.com/odata/mysql

Or this "Auto-generate a REST API from an existing MySQL DB" - https://www.indiehackers.com/product/noco/auto-generate-a-rest-api-from-an-existing-mysql-db--Lt2CGDHrNrZVLZLMpaI

What rest/api you use depends on what back-end languages you feel the most comfortable with.

To be honest, what you really should be doing is putting a application specific rest/api in-front of your database so that, if the database credentials stored in your app get hacked, people can't just trash the database.

i.e. you should have a rest/api that imposes application specific security restrictions on what the client app can do.

Comment: Ohk ok sure will make a api and will hit that one, so what i initially thought was hitting db from here and from api will be similar. Thanks for explanation